# In which work did Euler invent the Euler Substitutions for a quadratic composed into a radical?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, euler

A famous technique in the modification of integrands is the set of “euler substitutions” that provide substitutions for the structure

$$\sqrt{ax^2 +bx+c}$$

That is a fairly common occurence in integration.

I looked on the wikipedia page, and did not find any reference to where Euler introduced them.

Does anybody know in which text euler introduces these substitutions?

Comment: I'd be surprised if Euler were really the first person to deal with this: surely the Bernoullis could do this kind of thing, considering the far fancier stuff they did...???

Comment: that's true. I just assumed euler invented these subs based on the name.